# Android any orientation XML layout

Tags: android, xml, screen-orientation, device-orientation

Hello I am trying to make my layout compatible with all orientation screen types (landscape/portrait). For that I am using `layout-land` and `layout-port`.

This works for devices that have only 2 orientation positions (landscape and portrait) but is not working if I rotate a device that supports 4 orientation positions (land left/right, port upside down/upside). Is working only on default land position but if I rotate the device on the other landscape position, android choose the `layout-port` layouts instead of `layout-land`.

How can I solve this problem in XML? Or the only solution is to manage myself the orientation changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the layout-land works.. the problem was that I managed the orientation change by myself and took only 2 types of orientation..

(I manage the orientation just to get down the app title and make it full screen in landscape..)

Thank you for your answers though

Answer (score 0):

Here you will notice that I just listen to the stage for the StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE event. When the event fires there are five possible orientations that the stage can be in: default, rotated left, rotated right, upside down, and unknown.

http://www.unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2010/09/27/air-for-android-screen-orientation/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using XML. You have to do programmatic. To detect orientation change  you can use **OrientationEventListener**

Answer (score 0):

Your targetSDK has to be 2.2 (when the reverseLandscape and reversePortrait orientations were introduced... pretty sure it was in 2.2) and your device has to support these orientations. For example a Sony Tablet S won't go into reverseLandscape but will do reversePortrait

Comment: Oh.. I have android sdk 2.1 .. so maybe that could be the problem?